# Media queries different visualization for mobile/desktop in with dev tools

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, media-queries

I have a problem with media queries using dev tools. Why if I select mobile my site (width 1440px) is displayed correctly while I select desktop the site is displayed differently? Is there a specific media query for the desktop devices? My result work only if I select mobile-device on dev tools. If I select desktop-device it seems to use the same version of the tablet query.

These are my queries:
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) -for tablet-
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) -for desktop-

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it is a "Live Server" extension problem. Maybe from last vs code update.